# R: read the first column and then the rest

Tags: r

I have a file with codes and their descriptions. The code is always a short (3-6 characters) string of letters, separated from the following description by a space. Description is usually several words (also with spaces). 
Here is the example:

```
LIISS License Issued
LIMOD License Modified
LIPASS License Assigned (Partial Assignment)
LIPND License Assigned (Partition/Disaggregation)
LIPPND License Issued from a Partial/P&D Assignment
LIPUR License Purged
LIREIN License Reinstated
LIREN License Renewed
```

I'd like to read it as a 2-column data frame with the code in the first column and the description in the second one. How can I do this with R?

Comment: post a reproducible example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `stri_split_fixed()` from *stringi*

```
library(stringi)
as.data.frame(stri_split_fixed(readLines("x.txt"), " ", n = 2, simplify = TRUE))
#       V1                                           V2
# 1  LIISS                               License Issued
# 2  LIMOD                             License Modified
# 3 LIPASS        License Assigned (Partial Assignment)
# 4  LIPND  License Assigned (Partition/Disaggregation)
# 5 LIPPND License Issued from a Partial/P&D Assignment
# 6  LIPUR                               License Purged
# 7 LIREIN                           License Reinstated
# 8  LIREN                              License Renewed
```

Here we use `readLines()` to read the file (shown by `"x.txt"`).  Then `stri_split_fixed()` says that we want to split on a space, and want `n = 2` columns in return (thereby only splitting on the first space). `simplify = TRUE` is used to return a matrix instead of a list.

**Data:** *x.txt*

```
writeLines("LIISS License Issued
LIMOD License Modified
LIPASS License Assigned (Partial Assignment)
LIPND License Assigned (Partition/Disaggregation)
LIPPND License Issued from a Partial/P&D Assignment
LIPUR License Purged
LIREIN License Reinstated
LIREN License Renewed", "x.txt")
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks, Richard!

Answer (score 2):

We could read this using `readLines` and then create a two column `data.frame` by using `sub`

```
#read the lines with readLines
lines <- readLines('pavel.txt')
#match one or more spaces followed by one or more characters
#replace with `''` to extract the non-space characters at the beginning.
str1 <- sub('\\s+.*', '', lines)
#match non space characters from the beginning (`^[^ ]+`) followed by space
#replace with `''` to extract the characters that follow after the space.
str2 <- sub('^[^ ]+\\s+', '', lines)
out <- data.frame(v1= str1, v2=str2, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
head(out,3)
#      v1                                    v2
#1  LIISS                        License Issued
#2  LIMOD                      License Modified
#3 LIPASS License Assigned (Partial Assignment)
```

---

Or another option is `extract` from `library(tidyr)` after reading the dataset as a single column. We use capture groups to extract the characters we need in each column.  Here the `([^ ]+)` matches one or more non-spaces and is captured with parentheses, followed by one or more spaces (which we delete) and then use the second capture group to extract the rest of the characters.

```
library(tidyr)
extract(read.table('pavel.txt', sep=','), V1, 
                 into= c('V1', 'V2'), '([^ ]+)\\s+(.*)')
#      V1                                           V2
#1  LIISS                               License Issued
#2  LIMOD                             License Modified
#3 LIPASS        License Assigned (Partial Assignment)
#4  LIPND  License Assigned (Partition/Disaggregation)
#5 LIPPND License Issued from a Partial/P&D Assignment
#6  LIPUR                               License Purged
#7 LIREIN                           License Reinstated
#8  LIREN                              License Renewed
```

---

Or we could replace the first space with `,` then use `read.csv` with `sep=','`.

```
read.table(text=sub(' ', ',', readLines('pavel.txt')), sep=',')
#      V1                                           V2
#1  LIISS                               License Issued
#2  LIMOD                             License Modified
#3 LIPASS        License Assigned (Partial Assignment)
#4  LIPND  License Assigned (Partition/Disaggregation)
#5 LIPPND License Issued from a Partial/P&D Assignment
#6  LIPUR                               License Purged
#7 LIREIN                           License Reinstated
#8  LIREN                              License Renewed
```

If we are using linux, then `awk` can be piped with `fread` from `data.table` or `read.csv/read.table`.

```
library(data.table)
fread("awk '{sub(\" \", \",\", $0)}1' pavel.txt", header=FALSE)
#      V1                                           V2
#1:  LIISS                               License Issued
#2:  LIMOD                             License Modified
#3: LIPASS        License Assigned (Partial Assignment)
#4:  LIPND  License Assigned (Partition/Disaggregation)
#5: LIPPND License Issued from a Partial/P&D Assignment
#6:  LIPUR                               License Purged
#7: LIREIN                           License Reinstated
#8:  LIREN                              License Renewed
```